# pdfkit save empty pdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am running on Mac, successfully download and install pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf(via pkg).

I use bs4 to visit a few html page and would like to save them into pdf format.

I use pdfkit.from_url but it save me a blank page.

I have saved and check the html downloaded by bs4 and it is fine.

So what is the problem please?